# Documente inside a vhdl process with doxygen

Tags: vhdl, doxygen

I'm documenting my VHDL project with doxygen. I have a problem when I try to documentate the statements inside a process. If I try with `"--!"` the comment doesn't appear in doxygen HTML output.

Can statements inside a process (if, when... case) be docummented? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: as far as I know not. Only when you set \internal and INTERNAL_DOCS there might be some possibilities, but I don't know how far this is implemented in the VHDL parser for doxygen. I think that commands like \param, \brief, \details ... don't work here at all.

Comment: Thanks! @albert It worked. Sadly, as you said, is not so far implemented... :(

Comment: @ferdepe - What did you mean by "it worked"?  I tried \internal with INTERNAL_DOCS=YES.  I also made sure HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS=NO. The effect for me was that all \internal commands inside the process were ignored except the last one, and that last one appeared in the description of the next adjacent process in the source file.